# OSX testing website between 2 virtual computers

Tags: linux, macos, windows-10, virtual-machine

In an **OSX** host, is it possible to host 2 vitual machines, uBuntu and Windows 10, build a website in **uBuntu** and test it on Internet Explorer in **Windows 10**?

I'm trying to convince my employer a Mac is a better web development computer compared to a Windows or Linux computer.

My situation is that I have been issued a Microsoft Surface tablet for my new job. I looks and feels great but I'm not impressed with it as I use a Mac at home.

In addition, **Virtualbox**, **VMWare** and **Hyper-V** all seem to have one issue or another when I try to create an uBuntu guest. (*it was suggested to me there are probably no Linux drivers for the graphics card*)

So I need to make a case for a difference device justifying the expenditure.

Comment: I have use all three of those hypervisors and I have never had a problem running Linux within a virtual machine.

Comment: @Ramhound: I have used VirtualBox on different computers for years and never had such frustrations as I do now. I'm not sure what the source of the problem is but it doesn't perform well

Comment: Setting up the VMs is very simple - I'd use Parallels even though it's not the cheapest method. Full inter-connectivity I haven't explored, but you can assign fixed VM IPs so you ought to be able to achieve that.

Comment: @sisko - It sounds like you have a good candidate for a question.  This question isn't really that good of a question.  Intel has Linux display drivers so what you have been told isn't exactly true.  The only question that can be answered is a Yes or No type question.  It sounds like you really want to understand the reason you are having problems running Linux within a VM.

Comment: At some point it might need testing from a Mac [some developers actually do that, but only some]... you need a Mac to do that ;-)